# jQuery dynamic loading contents

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic-content

I have a problem with dynamic loading contents. I have the menu where after div clicking is hiding, they are loading new contents and he is moving.. it works correctly, however in new contents I have submenu, which would like to use the same effect for what for the menu, however is coming into existence the problem and the link cause the immediate passage

Maybe it's more understandable:) :  I have CONTNET DIV, which is dynamic loading If I click link in MENU... The new content is loading correctly. In new content I have submenu but if I click links there all site is reloaded... What I can do if I want loading only 'content div'..

What's is wrong in code ?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('.nav li a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
            $('#content').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });

    $('.nav li a').click(function(){

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;

    });

});
```

I tried to use your advice , but it doesn't effect..

I did example page..

http://zaciszepuck.pl/site/

You can see, if you click on menu, all it's ok, but if you are going to click submenu in 'welcome content' all site are reloaded, but if you click again, only Content Div is loaded..

anybody has an idea ?

Comment: please, correct your english - it is hard to understang your question.

Comment: @shybovycha, *oh*, the *irony* of that comment... =)

Comment: @David Thomas, it's 01:20 am on my clock, so i'm a little tired... Could you explain your phrase, please? =)

Comment: Maybe it's more understandable:) : I have CONTNET DIV, which is dynamic loading If I click link in MENU... The new content is loading correctly. In new content I have submenu but if I click links there all site is reloaded... What I can do if I want loading only 'content div'..

Comment: @shybovchya, I was referring to your request for the OP to correct his English, in a comment where **1** you began a sentence with a lower-case letter, **2** spelled 'english' in lower-case (English is a proper noun, so should be capitalised) and **3** mis-spelled 'understand.' ...I only meant it to be in good humour, though spelling it out now feels a little *mean*, so my sincere apologies for that.I do agree with you that the question is unclear, though.

Comment: @David Thomas, oh... really... i put case sensitiveness away sometimes, so i am sorry too.

Comment: @przemek, why don't you use `$("#content > a").click(function() { ... return false; });` within the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` ?

Comment: @shybovycha, but it works only for first click... hmm

Comment: @przemek, are you sure you are using right selector (jquery) and/or it selects right elements?

Answer (score 0):

What is your native language? I think it would be easier to answer in it.

Is it right? You click in main menu any item and load to the page new menu using AJAX, but items in new menu doesn't call AJAX request?

If it is so, you need to apply the AJAX function call to the new menu, its items or the hole loaded content, as you like.

```
$(".nav li a").click(function funcName() {
    ...
    $("#content").load(toLoad, function (){
        showNewContent();
        $(".nav li a").click(funcName);/*or other submenu selector*/
    });
    ...
});
```

I think your code is too complicated at all, it needs some improvements.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand of your query, this might do it.

```
$('.nav li a, #content a').live('click', function(){

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;

    });
```